# Group by date from a specific time to time in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to group data by date from a specific time of a date to a time in next date.
I've a `bills` table in Postgresql database with the following columns:

```
id serial NOT NULL,
bill_amount double precision,
tax_amount double precision,
discount double precision,
grand_total double precision,
created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
```

I want group by clause like from date `2015-09-12 06:00:00.00000` to date `2015-09-13 06:00:00.00000`, means all records less than `2015-09-13 06:00:00.00000` and greater than `2015-09-12 06:00:00.00000` will be considered as data of 12th September. So if I want to get the data of a month with group by date, is it possible?

Comment: NO, If you are looking for inbuilt rails methods to solve it. Logic you can always have around the idea

Answer (score 0):

In Postgresql you could use this as your grouping expression:

```
date_trunc('day',created_at-interval '6h')
```

(assuming `created_at` is the field you are wanting to group by).

I am no Rails expert, but glancing through the documentation I formed the opinion you might be able to get it to issue such SQL with something like

```
Bills.select("date_trunc('day',created_at-interval '6h') as day")
    .group("date_trunc('day',created_at-interval '6h')")
```

Incidentally, I am guessing the reason you want the days to run from 06:00 to 06:00 is that the timezones of the date columns are not aligned - you would be better off to either ensure that the data stored in these columns is aligned so that days run from 00:00 - 00:00, or to use `timestamp with timezone` as the type of these columns if the table will store data from multiple time zones.